# CSS - Can I resize the background image by changing the width and height?

Tags: css

Given the following CSS rule,

```
#block1 {
 text-indent: -1000em;
 background: transparent url(../images/xxx.png) no-repeat scroll center center;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Assume the image xxx.png is of dimension 100px by 50px. If I need to make this image displayed on #block1 looks smaller, can I simply change the width and height of #block1 or I have to first re-size the image and then change the width and height of the #block1 accordingly.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in CSS1 and 2, but CSS3 supports the [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size) property, which if you set to 100% should give you what you are looking for.

However, you probably should just resize the background image though, unless you have a compelling reason not to :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS can only position the image, not adjust it.  If you absolutely needed to resize the image through CSS, you'd have to have the image actually inserted as an `img` tag, then position it behind the content.  It's best just to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

no, the image will just appear to be cropped.